# Записать сообщения об ошибках при восстановлении БД в лог-файл

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu 20 + mysql на VDS.

Создал бэкап базы данных mySQL в архивы db1.sql.zst,... db10.sql.zst:

```
mysqldump -uroot user2_db 'table1' --opt --no-create-info --where='id>0 and id<=20000000' | zstd > /backup/db1.sql.zst
...
mysqldump -uroot user2_db 'table1' --opt --no-create-info --where='id>180000000 and id<=200000000' | zstd > /backup/db10.sql.zst
```

Восстановление бд занимает продолжительное время. А терминал putty может в любое время переподключиться к серверу из-за обрыва связи (домашний интернет). Поэтому комманды восстановления записываю в скрипт restore.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
zstd -d < /backup/db1.sql.zst | mysql -uroot user2_db;
...
zstd -d < /backup/db10..sql.zst | mysql -uroot user2_db;
```

запускаю его через crontab -e, и иду спать).
К утру восстановление завершается.

Необходимо изменить скрипт restore.sh так, чтобы любые сообщения об ошибках и предупреждениях от zstd и mysql писались в файл /backup/restore.log.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Надеюсь правильно понял, добавьте второй строкой в скрипте после объявления интерпретатора: `exec >> /backup/restore.log 2>&1` - вывод всех команд из stdout и stderr в скрипте будет перенаправлен на запись в файл /backup/restore.log

Comment: Добавить сразу после "#!/bin/bash" ? А другие скрипты также начнут писать в этот лог, пока не перезагрузишь Ubuntu?

Comment: Да, на новой строке после `#!/bin/bash`, Это только для скрипта будет действовать, в который будет внесено и перезагрузка на это влиять не будет. Т.е. перенаправление вывода будет только тех команд которые прописаны в скрипте, где эту строку добавите. Ради теста, что бы было понятнее, создайте скрипт, который будет возвращать ошибку, к примеру `ls /sdsdsds/` и вывод в stdout `echo "stdout текст"`, и запустите его, посмотрите что появилось в логе.

Comment: а если скрипт не нужно исполнять регулярно, то проще будет не шаманить с `cron`'ом, а просто запустить его как `nohup ./foo.sh >/backup/restore.log 2>&1` или же внутри `tmux`'а...